# Do we reduce the problem into the known $3^x+4^x=5^x $?

Tags: calculus, analysis

I want to solve the following equations: \begin{align*}&(i) \ \ \ \ \ 3^x+4^x=5^x \\ &(ii) \ \ \ \ \ (x+1)^x+(x+2)^x=(x+3)^x, \ x>-1 \\ &(iii) \ \ \ \ \ (x+1)^x+(x+2)^x=(x+4)^x, \ x>-1\end{align*}

$$$$

I have done the following:

For (i):

We have that $$3^x+4^x=5^x\Rightarrow \left (\frac{3}{5}\right )^x+\left (\frac{4}{5}\right )^x=1$$ This equation of the form $f(x)=a^x+b^x$ with $0<a<b<1$. For this equation we have that: Since $0<a,b<1$ the function $a^x$ and $b^x$ and so also $f(x)$ are decreasing.

So there is at most one solution.

Since $a<b$ so $a^x<b^x$ for positive $x$ then we get $2a^x<f(x)<2b^x$. Both the lower and upper bound for $f(x)$ pass through 1, we know that f(x) must also pass through 1, so there is exactly one solution,.

We symbolize by $c$ the unique solution. From $2a^c<1<2b^c$ we get the inequality $-\log_a2<c<-\log_b2$. For $a=\frac{3}{5}$ and $b=\frac{4}{5}$ we get $1.35<c<3.10$. We consider the natural numers between $1.35$ and $3,10$.

We see that for $c=2$ the equation is satisfied, and so $x=2$ is the only solution.

Is everything correct?

As for (ii) and (iii) do we have to find an appropriate $x$ so that we can reduce it to a problem as in (i) ?

Comment: Well, there are obvious solutions to both $ii$ and $iii$....

Comment: After saying that $(3/5)^x+(4/5)^x$ is (strictly) decreasing, then you have at most one solution for $(3/5)^x+(4/5)^x=1$, and therefore $x=2$ is the only solution. Why did you bother in doing more steps?

Comment: Which are the steps that are not needed? Could you give me a hint for (ii) and (iii) ? Do we have to find a $x$ to reduce each equation to the equation of (i) ? @JulianMejia

Comment: At (ii) for $x=2$ we get the equation of (i),right? But how can we prove that? @lulu

Comment: For $x=2$, you don't "get the equation of $(i)$", you get no equation at all, as $x$ is set !

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach**

$x=2$ is an obvious solution to the problem. So consider the function
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x-1.$$
We know $f(2)=0$. Also $f'(x)=\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x\ln\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x \ln\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) <0$ for all $x$. Should this $f$ had another zero, say $f(c)=0$, then by Rolle's theorem, there exists a point $k \in (c,2)$ (or $(2,c)$) such that $f'(k)=0$ but thay contradicts the sign of the derivative we have shown above. Thus only one solution.

Comment: Ok! Thanks!! Could you give me a hint for the equations (ii) and (iii) ? As for (ii) for $x=2$ we get the equation (i). Then we have to show that there is no other solution, right? Do we do that in the same way as in (i) ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your last question: no this would not work. Finding an appropriate $x$ would mean… that you have solved the equation.

You can try the same "monotonicity trick", but the function is more complicated:

$$\left (\frac{x+1}{x+3}\right )^x+\left (\frac{x+2}{x+3}\right )^x=1$$

---

Note that a function like

$$\left (\frac{x+1}{x+3}\right )^x=\left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )^x$$ tends to a finite value ($e^{-2}$) and it is not completely obvious that it is decreasing.

Comment: Ok! But how can we show that the function is decreasing? I don't see how we can do that. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @MaryStar: sign of the derivative ?

Comment: We have that $$g(x)=\left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )^x=e^{\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )^x}=e^{x\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )}$$

Comment: Then  $$g'(x)=e^{x\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )}\cdot \left (\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )+x\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{x+3}}\cdot \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )'\right )=e^{x\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )}\cdot \left (\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )+x\cdot \frac{x+3}{x+1}\cdot\frac{2}{(x+3)^2}\right )=e^{x\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )}\cdot \left (\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )+x\cdot \frac{1}{x+1}\cdot\frac{2}{x+3}\right )=e^{x\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )}\cdot \left (\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )+x\cdot \frac{2}{(x+1)(x+3)}\right )$$

Comment: The logarithm is positiv when: $1-\frac{2}{x+3}>1\Rightarrow \frac{2}{x+3}<0 \Rightarrow x+3<0 \Rightarrow x<-3$. Since it is given that $x>-1$ we have that the logarithm is negativ. So we have to check the sign of the whole parethesis. How could we do that?

Comment: @MaryStar: use the logarithmic derivative, it is easier to show it negative (it is growing and tends to $0$).

Comment: Do you mean to calculate the derivative using the formula $$\left [ u(x)^{v(x)}\right ]'=u(x)^{v(x)}\left [\ln (u(x))\cdot v(x)\right ]'$$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: no, I mean that yo compute the derivative of the logarithm.

Comment: So do you mean to take the parenthesis, let $h(x)=\ln \left (1-\frac{2}{x+3}\right )+\frac{2x}{(x+1)(x+3)}$ and check the sign of that calculating the derivative? Or have I understodd that wrong?

Comment: Or do you mean something else by computing the derivative of the logarithm?

Comment: @MaryStar: you got it.

Comment: We have that $$h'(x)=\frac{8x+12}{(x^2+4x+3)^2}>0$$ so $h$ is increasing. Then for $x>-1$ we have that $h(x)>h(-1)$, right?

Comment: But $h(-1)$ is not defined. Do we have to take the limit? Or do we not use this here?

Comment: @MaryStar: what matters is $h(\infty)$.

Comment: Ahh you mean $x<\infty\Rightarrow h(x)<h(\infty)=0$ ?

Comment: Then we do the same for $\left (\frac{x+2}{x+3}\right )^x$ and then we have that there is at most one solution and since $x=2$ solves the equation, it is the only solution, right? And then we do the same also for (iii), right?